# Eval error Argument list too long when expandind a command

Tags: bash

I got some code from here that works pretty well until I get "Argument list too long" 
I am NOT a developer and pretty old too :) so if it is not much to ask please explain.

Is there a way the expand DIRCMD like eval does and pass each of the commands one at the time so eval does not break?

```
for (( ifl=0;ifl<$((NUMFIRSTLEVELDIRS));ifl++ )) {  FLDIR="$(get_rand_dirname)"
FLCHILDREN="";
for (( ird=0;ird<$((DIRDEPTH-1));ird++ )) {
DIRCHILDREN=""; MOREDC=0;
for ((idc=0; idc<$((MINDIRCHILDREN+RANDOM%MAXDIRCHILDREN)); idc++)) {
CDIR="$(get_rand_dirname)" ;
# make sure comma is last, so brace expansion works even for 1 element? that can mess with expansion     math, though
if [ "$DIRCHILDREN" == "" ]; then 
DIRCHILDREN="\"$CDIR\"" ;
else 
DIRCHILDREN="$DIRCHILDREN,\"$CDIR\"" ;
MOREDC=1 ;
fi
}
if [ "$MOREDC" == "1" ] ; then
if [ "$FLCHILDREN" == "" ]; then 
FLCHILDREN="{$DIRCHILDREN}" ;
else 
FLCHILDREN="$FLCHILDREN/{$DIRCHILDREN}" ;
fi
else
if [ "$FLCHILDREN" == "" ]; then 
FLCHILDREN="$DIRCHILDREN" ;
else 
FLCHILDREN="$FLCHILDREN/$DIRCHILDREN" ;
fi
fi
}
cd $OUTDIR
DIRCMD="mkdir -p $OUTDIR/\"$FLDIR\"/$FLCHILDREN"
eval "$DIRCMD"
echo "$DIRCMD"
}
```

I tried echo $DIRCMD but do not get the expanded list of commands
'echo mkdir -p /mnt/nvme-test/rndpath/"r8oF"/{"rc","XXKR","p0H"}/{"5Dw0K","oT","rV","coU","uo"}/{"3m5m","uEdA","w4SJp","49"}'

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble following the code, but if I understood it correctly, you dynamically generate a `mkdir -p` command with a brace expansion:

```
'mkdir -p /mnt/nvme-test/rndpath/"r8oF"/{"rc","XXKR","p0H"}/{"5Dw0K","oT","rV","coU","uo"}/{"3m5m","uEdA","w4SJp","49"}'
```

Which then fails when you `eval` it due to your OS' maximum argument limit.

To get around that, you can instead generate a `printf ..` command since this is a Bash builtin and not subject to the argument limit, and feed its output to `xargs`:

```
dircmd='printf "%s\0" /mnt/nvme-test/rndpath/"r8oF"/{"rc","XXKR","p0H"}/{"5Dw0K","oT","rV","coU","uo"}/{"3m5m","uEdA","w4SJp","49"}'
eval "$dircmd" | xargs -0 mkdir -p
```

If your `xargs` doesn't support `-0`, you can instead use `printf "%s\n"` and `xargs mkdir -p`, though it won't behave as well if your generated names contain spaces and such.

If this is for benchmarking, you may additionally be interested to know that you can now use `xargs -0 -n 1000 -P 8 mkdir -p` to run 8 `mkdir`s in parallel, each creating 1000 dirs at a time.

Comment: So in my case the equivalent of

Comment: @thatotheruy, when I define dircmd='printf "%s\0 " $OUTDIR/\"$FLDIR\"/$FLCHILDREN  
the command is not getting expanded  
└── [       4096]  BY3O
    └── [       4096]  {ky,j,BF9}
        └── [       4096]  {qc6,UXiAi,QN}
            └── [       4096]  {u,1,D3,l3}
   
when I do this >>> eval "$dircmd5" | xargs  mkdir -p

Comment: Just one more bump to get me over the hump please

Comment: I don't follow. The command in the variable must be a valid shell command with brace expansion, such as `printf '%s\0' /mnt/foo/{a,b,c}/{d,e,f}`. Make sure it's correct with e.g. `echo` first. I don't know what `└── [ 4096] BY3O` is meant to indicate.